# Ask about how to sum 1 + 01 =02 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

How get the number with format is leading zero `ex:01`
and how to make format number like that my problem is from this query

```
$try= $this->login->get_id_child('00',3);
$count_try = count($try);
$id ="00";
$new = $id.$count_try;
echo $new;
```

the result from `echo $new` is `003`

data in array `$try=array(000,001,002)` and try is count by `$count_try` the result is `3`. but I want to make the result  from `$count_try` is `03` so I can join that variable to my id so I can get `$new=00003`  but if the data in

```
$try=array(000,001,002,003,004,005,006,007,008,009);
```

so the value of `$new` is `0010`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_pad` -

```
echo str_pad($new, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

[str_pad()](http://php.net/str_pad)

**Update**

```
    $count_try = 10;
    $new = str_pad($count_try, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo $new;
```

Comment: thank's for the answer, i was us it but i have problem if i get the data in `$try` is more than 9 i will get the resul `$new=00010` but i want to get the result is `0010`

Comment: You dont have to concatenate that `$id` i think. Just set the socond parameter to `4`

Comment: hehe thanks i get it case close

Comment: @nanasjr - numbers prefixed with a `0` in PHP are treated as `octal` values, and `0008` is invalid octal and treated as `0`

Comment: so i must use like what? i just want get number like that for numbering some data with tree structure data

Comment: For that it will work i think. give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$id ="0010";
$new = (int) $id + 1;
$new = str_pad($new, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $new; //0011
```